# android mp3 bitrate increase if remove ID3 tags

Tags: android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

If we remove ID3 tags for MP3 file e.g. Embedded Image, Some Meta Information and then try to stream mp3 over the internet, will the BIT RATE of mp3 will increase?

I am asking this because, I have network constraints for the project I'm working on and need to increase bit rate and file size of mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the bitrate is determined at encoding time and doesn't change.  It's a measurement of how much data is used to encode the shape of the sound wave.  Removing metadata from a file doesn't add information about the sound wave.

Removing metadata will (slightly) reduce the size of the file and the amount of network bandwidth needed to stream it.  But I think the usual meaning of "bitrate" only relates to the audio stream, not the entire file (audio plus metadata).

Comment: thanks sir. so if we remove meta then streaming over network can be fast but mediaplayer will play at defined bitrate

Comment: The audio data is the same regardless of whether it's accompanied by metadata.  If you want a higher audio bitrate — that is, if you want your MP3 to include more detailed information about the shape of the original sound wave — you have to go back to your uncompressed source and re-encode with a different quality setting.